# Get attribute from element

Tags: jquery

I have couple similar elements and I need to get a value from each. The only difference between the two is differentiating class.

```
<div id="box_1231231" class="myItem boxItem"></div>
<div id="toy_1231231" class="myItem toyItem"></div>
```

```js
$(document).delegate('.myItem', 'mouseup', function() {
    var key_box = ($(this).hasClass('.boxItem').attr('id')).replace('box_', ''),
        val_box = $(this).hasClass('.boxItem').val(),
        val_toy = $(this).hasClass('.toyItem').val();
    ...
});
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).hasClass(...).attr is not a function.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `hasClass` returns a boolean value, which does not have the `attr` method. I'm not sure what logic you're expecting here.

Comment: Why the parenthesis around `($(this).hasClass('.boxItem').attr('id'))`? And divs don't have value attributes.

Comment: try $(this).hasClass('boxItem').val() i.e. without ./period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasClass` returns a boolean value which does not have the `attr` method. If I've understood what you're trying to do, you need to use an `if` statement:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.myItem', function() {
    var $el = $(this);

    if ($el.hasClass('boxItem')) {
        var key_box = $el.attr('id').replace('box_', '');
        var val_box = $el.val();

        // your logic here...
    }
    else if ($el.hasClass('toyItem')) {
        var val_toy = $el.val();

        // your logic here...
    }
});
```

Also note that I amended `delegate` to the newer `on` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Use as, Remove `.` while fetching

```
 $(this).hasClass('toyItem')
 $(this).hasClass('boxItem')
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)